# UITabBarDelegate in AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabController in my main window, and would like to add some logic when each tab is selected. I've added the delegate to the header file:

```
@interface MyAppAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarDelegate> {
```

I have a method for the tab change event:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
    //some code
}
```

But the code inside the didSelectItem method isn't called. I've connected the delegate for the UITabBarController to my AppDelegate in IB. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: `didSelectItem` is the method you need. can you show how you set the delegate of your tab bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting it in the viewWillAppear method of the view in the specific tab I need. Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you assign the delegate via IB, you should connect the delegate for your TabBar (as opposed to your TabBarController) to your app delegate.

[image]

Indeed, you are not looking for the [`UITabBarControllerDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), but for the [`UITabBarDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

If you do it programmatically, then, from your tab bar controller `viewDidLoad` execute:

```
self.tabBar.delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

Comment: Good idea, unfortunately, it then crashes with an error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Changing the delegate of a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'`

Comment: I see... in this case I suspect that your only chance to use `didSelectItem` is using `UITabBar` directly without a `UITabBarController`. Or, try subclassing UITabBarController and *only* override `didSelectItem` (I guess the controller is the delegate for the tab bar; not sure that it will work, but you can try).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `UITabbarController` you can use `UITabBarControllerDelegate` instead of `UITabBarDelegate`.

Then, you can set `self.delegate = self`. Then you use:

```
 (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

instead of:

```
 (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you assign some class to be the tab bar's delegate? Something like

```
myTabBar.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but no effect. Could it have something to do with the delegate being the AppDelegate itself? Is there perhaps some rule somewhere which says if it's the AppDelegate, it can't be any other type of delegate?

Answer (score 0):

i might be out on a ledge here but i think the signature of the method should be:

```
- (IBAction)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

and then you connect it to the tabbar in IB. after you change to IBAction it should appear in IB